# INSERT INTO por alguna razon no funciona

Tags: php

me ayudan a ver que esta mal? no encuentro el problema. No da error de conexion. La variable $conexion se encuentra dentro de conecta.php.

**FORMULARIO**

```
 <form action="welcome.php" method="POST" class="login">
        <select required name="usuario_registro">

            <option name="administrador"  value="administrador">Administrador</option>

            <option name="propietario" value="propietario" selected>Propietario</option>

            <option name="inquilino" value="inquilino">Inquilino</option>


        </select> <br> <br>

        <input type="text" required name="nombre" id="email" placeholder="Cual es tu nombre"><br>
        <input type="text" required name="apellido" id="email" placeholder="Tu apellido?"><br>
        <input type="text" required name="email" id="email" placeholder="Ingresa tu Email"><br>
        <input type="text" required name="password" id="clave" placeholder="Crea una clave"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="registrando" id="entrar" value="Registrame" class="btn btn-link">
        <p>Ya tienes una cuenta?</p>
        <a href="index.php">Ingresa ahora!</a>
    </form>
```

**PAGINA DE RECEPCION**

```
 <?php 

        $registro_tipo=$_POST['usuario_registro'];
        $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
        $apellido=$_POST['apellido'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $pass=$_POST['password'];

        require ("config/conecta.php");


    $sql="

    INSERT INTO usuarios 

    (

    usuario_registro,
    nombre,
    apellido,
    email,
    password   

    ) VALUES (

    '$registro_tipo', 
    '$nombre', 
    '$apellido',
    '$email', 
    '$pass'

    )

    ";

    $resultados=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);


    if($resultados==false) {

            echo " No funciona";
    }
```

Comment: Haz que tu código hable, así sabrás lo que está fallando. En vez de poner un simple "No funciona", pon esto: **`echo " No funciona. El error es: ".mysqli_error($conexion);`** Ya nos dirás lo que te imprime.

Comment: Muchas gracias a ver!!

Comment: El error que tiro es el siguiente. No funciona. El error es: Field 'edificio' doesn't have a default value .  yo no puse todos los campos de la tabla usuarios, solo los que quiero que se completen.. Debo especificar todos los campos de la tabla?

Comment: @NicoWebs entonces a esa columna establecele un valor DEFAULT

Comment: Ohhh ... !viste cómo habló de rápido! Al parecer en tu tabla hay una columna llamada `edificio` que no admite nulos ni tiene declarado un valor por defecto. Al no incluirla en el `INSERT` te advierte del fallo. Debes asignar un valor por defecto a `edificio` para cuando este no intervenga en el `INSERT` o modificar el diseño de la BD según el contexto, por ejemplo, permitiendo que `edificio` admita valores `NULL`. Eso sí, antes de cualquier cambio debes estar seguro de lo que estás haciendo, no sea que crees un caos en el sistema.

Comment: muchas gracias!!! si le pongo NULL a la tabla deberia funciona cierto?

Comment: puff!! muchas gracias!!! le puse null a los campos no asignados en el INSERT y anduvo perfecto!! muchas gracias! ustedes me ayudan a aprender!! Nico

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que trabajes tus operaciones a la base de datos a través de consultas preparadas, noto por el uso de `mysqli_query()` que te conectas a través de mysqli, por lo que aquí te dejo como debería ir tu código

```
<?php

$registro_tipo=$_POST['usuario_registro'];
        $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
        $apellido=$_POST['apellido'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $pass=$_POST['password'];

        require ("config/conecta.php");

$alta = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios(usuario_registro, nombre, apellido, email, password) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
$alta->bind_param("sssss", $registro_tipo, $nombre, $apellido, $email, $pass);
$alta->execute();
```

**OBSERVACIONES**

1. En lugar de colocar las variables directo en la sentencia SQL, coloco un marcador de posición por medio del signo `?`
2. Hago uso del método `bind_param()` para indicarle por medio de `s` que los valores todos son de tipo string y posterior las variables por medio de las cuales hará el intercambio por cada marcador de posición
3. Hago uso de `prepare()`para crear la consulta preparada
4. Con el método `execute()` proceso dicha consulta

Tienes las siguientes opciones para identificar los tipos de datos

1. i -> integer
2. d -> double
3. s -> string

Comment: Buena respuesta, que indica el camino correcto con respecto a la seguridad. Pero yo verificaría las variables *esenciales*  del POST, o sea, aquellas sin la cual no se podría crear un registro. Si alguna de ellas estuviese vacía la consulta no debería ejecutarse.

Comment: tienes razón @A.Cedano me adelanté y ya vi en la zona de comentarios del OP, cual era el fallo

Comment: De todos modos tu respuesta es buena, porque ayuda al OP a implementar la práctica correcta en cuanto a la seguridad mediante el uso de consultas preparadas. Ojalá que él opte por esta solución. Saludos.

Comment: Ahora que solucione el problema que lo tenia en las tablas, voy a pasarlo a consultas prepararas. Estoy aprendiendo! son de mucha ayuda! gracias! Nico

Comment: Alguien podria explicarme para que son los SSSSS en el campo? Se que especifica un texto pero no entiendo mucho cual es la funcion. gracias

Comment: ayudar en la consulta preparada, para identificar el tipo de dato que se espera llegue, en caso de coincidir, avanzar para ejecutar la consulta @NicoWebs

Comment: @NicoWebs las `s` indican el tipo de dato. Si la columna respectiva es `VARCHAR` se pone una `s` (de **s**tring) y si fuera un número se pondría una `i` (de **i**nteger). [Está explicado en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) revisa el apartado titulado **Parámetros**, donde dice: ***types***. Cada letra se pone según el orden de la columna en la sentencia, para que corresponda.

Answer (score 0):

También puedes usar el objeto `PDO` para la conexión:

```
$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=myhost.com;dbname=mydb',myDbUser,myDbPass);
```

Entonces para hacer tus query's usarías la siguiente manera:

```
$statement = $connection->prepare('SELECT name,author,price,year FROM books WHERE year BETWEEN :year1 AND :year2');
$result = $statement->execute(array(':year1'=>1993,':year2'=>2000));
```

Como puedes ver al momento de ejecutar el SQL le pasamos un array asociativo como argumentos para asignarle un valor a los aleas que pusimos con dos puntos antes del nombre en el SQL.

Comment: si revisas, claramente el OP maneja mysqli

Comment: Solo es una sugerencia